# Tapestry @Persist(PersistenceConstants.FLASH) issues with Tomcat but not Jetty

Tags: java, jetty, tomcat7, tapestry

I was facing an issue deploying my application based on Tapestry 5.4 (AppFuse modular one). Hopefully i solved it, but i'm still wondering why ....

Tapestry provide a *simple* mechanism to store variables from one page to another, serialazing the object:

```
package com.corp.div.project.admin;

public class EmployeList {
    /* ... */
    @Persist(PersistenceConstants.FLASH)
    ComplexObject myObject;
}
```

The object was correctly passed through the requests when using jetty (with mvn :etty:run), but I got an Exception when using Tomcat (6 with maven plugin, or 7 on a fresh install) :

```
    Error persisting field admin/EmployeList:myObject: setAttribute: Non-serializable attribute flash:admin/EmployeList::myObject
```

Obviously, I added `implements Serialzable`to my class :

```
public class ComplexObject implements Serializable {

/**
 * UID
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -76621654341617565L;
```

But I'm still wondering why it works with jetty and not with Tomcat...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood, tapestry calls `HttpSession.setAttribute(...)` and as far as the servlet spec is concerned, this does not require the object to be `Serializable`.

Servlet containers will require session objects to be `Serializable` if they do the following

- Save / restore sessions from disk at shutdown / startup
- HTTPSession Clustering

By default, Tomcat saves / restores to disk whereas Jetty does not. This is why you see the issue on Tomcat but not Jetty. I'm sure that if you enabled Jetty's backup to disk (via [HashSessionManager](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/7.6.14.v20131031/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/session/HashSessionManager.html)) or you enabled clustering, you would see the same sorts of exceptions on Jetty.

So, as a rule of thumb, you should always make sure that your session attributes are `Serializable`. Perhaps you should configure Jetty's [HashSessionManager](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/7.6.14.v20131031/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/session/HashSessionManager.html) to get more consistent behaviour.

Comment: Thanks @Lance. Is sounds like what I red those days. Indeed, the I found many issues about Tomcat shutdown saves related to this error, and you explaination is quite clear. Thanks a lots :)